# «Не занятых» или «незанятых земель»?

Tags: частица-не

Из не занятых земель остались участки в пределах населённых пунктов Александровского сельского поселения и немного за пределами... «Не занятых» или «незанятых»

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **из незанятых земель.**

НЕ с одиночными причастиями пишется слитно (при отсутствии противопоставления или усиления отрицания).